# "Parameter not valid" exception loading System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, image, stream, argumentexception

Why am I getting the exception "Parameter not valid" in my code:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
```

The length of `byteArrayIn` is 169014. I am getting this exception despite the fact that no value in it is greater than 255.

Comment: please format your question properly

Comment: `none of value in it is not greater than 255` is phrased wrong, its double negative, making it positive. So you say that all the values are above 255. I guess you meant they are all less or equal to 255, which is an intrinsic barrier of a byte.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem and apparently is solved now, despite this and some other gdi+ exceptions are very misleading, I found that actually the problem was that the parameter being sent to a Bitmap constructor was not valid. I have this code:

```
using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(inputImage, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    try
    {
        using (Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(fs, true, false))
        {
            try
            {
                bitmap.Save(OutputImage + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                GC.Collect();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ArgumentException aex)
    {
        throw new Exception("The file received from the Map Server is not a valid jpeg image", aex);
    }
}
```

The following line was causing an error:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(fs, true, false)
```

The file stream was built from the file downloaded from the Map Server. My app was sending the request incorrectly to get the image, and the server was returning something with the jpg extension, but was actually a html telling me that an error ocurred. So I was taking that image and trying to build a Bitmap with it.
The fix was to control/ validate the image for a valid jpeg image.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 15):

My guess is that `byteArrayIn` doesn't contain valid image data.

Please give more information though:

- Which line of code is throwing an exception?
- What's the message?
- Where did you get `byteArrayIn` from, and are you sure it should contain a valid image?

Comment: Thanks Jon, this answer allowed me to find a solution to my Parameter is not valid exception. +1 for you

Comment: Indeed, I find that "Parameter is not valid" in that case almost always indicates corrupt/invalid data

Comment: in my case i was loading data from a file that did exist, but it had zero bytes.  Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
byte[] fileData = null;
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream))
{
    fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
}
ImageConverter imageConverter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
System.Drawing.Image image = imageConverter.ConvertFrom(fileData) as System.Drawing.Image;
image.Save(imageFullPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: This is the only working solution in my case, thank you! 
I've got few types of images to load and some of them couldn't load by Image.FromStream(). The ImageConverter can load them all :)

Comment: Thanks this helped me. by the way, you need to check the ContentLength>0, before executing the code.

Answer (score 7):

The "parameter is not valid" exception thrown by `Image.FromStream()` tells you that the stream is not a 'valid' or 'recognised' format. Watch the memory streams, especially if you are taking various offsets of bytes from a file.

```
// 1. Create a junk memory stream, pass it to Image.FromStream and 
// get the "parameter is not valid":
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(new Byte[] {0x00, 0x01, 0x02});
System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);`

// 2. Create a junk memory stream, pass it to Image.FromStream
// without verification:
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(new Byte[] {0x00, 0x01, 0x02});
System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, false, true);
```

Example 2 will work, note that useEmbeddedColorManagement must be false for validateImageData to be valid.

May be easiest to debug by dumping the memory stream to a file and inspecting the content.

Answer (score 3):

Which line is throwing the exception? The `new MemoryStream(...)`? or the `Image.FromStream(...)`? And what is the `byteArrayIn`? Is it a `byte[]`? I only ask because of the comment "And none of value in it is not greater than 255" - which of course  is automatic for a `byte[]`.

As a more obvious question: does the binary actually contain an image in a sensible format?

For example, the following (although not great code) works fine:

```
    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(@"d:\extn.png"); // not a good idea...
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
    Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
    Console.WriteLine(img.Width);
    Console.WriteLine(img.Height);
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by binary data being inserted into a buffer.
To solve this problem, you should insert one statement in your code.

This statement is:

```
obj_FileStream.Read(Img, 0, Convert.ToInt32(obj_FileStream.Length));
```

Example:

```
FileStream obj_FileStream = new FileStream(str_ImagePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
Byte[] Img = new Byte[obj_FileStream.Length];
obj_FileStream.Read(Img, 0, Convert.ToInt32(obj_FileStream.Length));         
dt_NewsFeedByRow.Rows[0][6] = Img;
```

Answer (score -2):

all the solutions given doesnt work.. dont concentrate only on the retrieving part. luk at the inserting of the image. i did the same mistake. I tuk an image from hard disk and saved it to database. The problem lies in the insert command. luk at my fault code..:

```
 public bool convertImage()
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            photo = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.Read(photo, 0, photo.Length);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("image can not be converted");
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void insertImage()
    {
       // SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        try
        {
            cs.Close();
            cs.Open();
            da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE All_students SET disco = " +photo+" WHERE Reg_no = '" + Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text)+ "'", cs);
            da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cs.Close();
            cs.Open();
            int i = da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (i > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Inserted...");
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in Connection");
        }
        cs.Close();
    }
```

The above code shows succesfully inserted... but actualy its saving the image in the form of wrong datatype.. whereas the datatype must bt "image".. so i improved the code..

```
  public bool convertImage()
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            photo = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.Read(photo, 0, photo.Length);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("image can not be converted");
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void insertImage()
    {
       // SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        try
        {
            cs.Close();
            cs.Open();
            //THIS WHERE THE CODE MUST BE CHANGED>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

            da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE All_students SET disco = @img WHERE Reg_no = '" + Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text)+ "'", cs);
            da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image);//CHANGED TO IMAGE DATATYPE...
            da.UpdateCommand.Parameters["@img"].Value = photo;
            da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cs.Close();
            cs.Open();
            int i = da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (i > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Inserted...");
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in Connection");
        }
        cs.Close();
    }
```

100% gurantee that there will be no PARAMETER NOT VALID error in retrieving....SOLVED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score -4):

Most of the time when this happens it is bad data in the SQL column. This is the proper way to insert into an image column:

```
INSERT INTO [TableX] (ImgColumn) VALUES (
(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\....\Picture 010.png', SINGLE_BLOB) as tempimg))
```

Most people do it incorrectly this way:

```
INSERT INTO [TableX] (ImgColumn) VALUES ('C:\....\Picture 010.png'))
```

Answer (score -6):

Just Follow this to Insert values into database

//Connection String

```
  con.Open();

sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Client] ([Client_ID],[Client_Name],[Phone],[Address],[Image]) VALUES('" + txtClientID.Text + "','" + txtClientName.Text + "','" + txtPhoneno.Text + "','" + txtaddress.Text + "',@image)";

                cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.Image);
                cmd.Parameters["@image"].Value = img;
            //img is a byte object
           ** /*MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms,pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
            byte[] img = ms.ToArray();*/**

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
```