# "Parameter is not valid" exception from System.Drawing.Image.FromStream() method

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.drawing

I got a hard time with the Image.FromStream method in my website. The code below works perfect on my computer. But when I uploaded it to the test server, it always gives me "Parameter not valid" exception.

```
if (!afuImageFile.IsUploading && afuImageFile.HasFile)
{
    System.Drawing.Image imgFile = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(afuImageFile.FileContent);
}
```

the `afuImageFile` is an `AsynFileUploader` control in Ajax Tool Kits. `afuImageFile.FileContent` is a `HttpInputStream`. I guess I need to add some permission to some folder. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sounds like a similar problem to this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614773/image-fromstreampostedfile-inputstream-fails-parameter-is-not-valid-async

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure that your `FileContent` stream as its position set to 0.

Otherwise, you might want to deactivate image validation by changing the call from:

```
System.Drawing.Image imgFile = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(afuImageFile.FileContent);
```

to:

```
System.Drawing.Image imgFile = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(afuImageFile.FileContent, true, false);
```

See [`Image.FromStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21zw9ah6(v=vs.110).aspx) to check on the other overloads.