# "Parameter is not valid" error when extracting images using iTextSharp from a PDF containing JPXDecode filter

Tags: image, pdf, filter, itext

I am trying to extract images from a PDF using the following code. It works well for some filters like DCTDecode , but is not working for JPXDEcode ."Parameter not valid " error occurs at the point image.GetDrawingImage() is called.

```
 using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
    using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
    ...
    PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader(currfilename);
     PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(pdf);
     ImageRender listener = new ImageRender();
     for (int i = 1; i <= pdf.NumberOfPages; i++)
     {
          try
          {
              parser.ProcessContent(i, listener);//calls RenderImage() at this point

           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
           }

      }


    public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
            {
                PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.GetImage();
                PdfName filter = image.Get(PdfName.FILTER) as PdfName;


                if (renderInfo.GetRef() != null && image != null)
                {
                    using (System.Drawing.Image dotnetImg = image.GetDrawingImage())//exception occurs at this point
                    {
                        if (dotnetImg != null)
                        {
                            ImageNames.Add(string.Format("{0}.tiff", renderInfo.GetRef().Number));
                            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                dotnetImg.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Tiff);
                                Images.Add(ms.ToArray());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }



            }
```

I tried these links for a solution

[Extract images using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802269/extract-images-using-itextsharp)

[Extract Image from a particular page in PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689382/extract-image-from-a-particular-page-in-pdf-using-itextsharp-4-0)

and was able  to extract the raw image bytes using PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw() function but "Parameter not valid "exception always occurs at the point where  System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memory stream) is called.

I also checked this link ["Parameter is not valid" exception from System.Drawing.Image.FromStream() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586878/parameter-is-not-valid-exception-from-system-drawing-image-fromstream-method)  , but could not find anything helpful.

Please help

Answer (score 3):

The [JPXDecode filter corresponds to JPEG 2000 compression](http://www.verypdf.com/document/pdf-format-reference/pg_0086.htm), which is not supported by .net framework. This other question in SO may help: [JPEG 2000 support in C#.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590471/jpeg-2000-support-in-c-net)

Comment: Thank you.. I will go through these

Answer (score 2):

Using FreeImage.dll solved the problem. The code is as follows

```
using FreeImageAPI;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
...
        imagecount = 0;
        PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader(currfilename);
        PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(pdf);
        ImageRender listener = new ImageRender();
        for (int i = 1; i <= pdf.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
         try
            {
                  parser.ProcessContent(i, listener);//calls RenderImage() at this point
            }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(e);
         }

       }
       if (listener.Images.Count > 0)
       {
           for (int j = 0; (j < listener.Images.Count); ++j)
           {
              string imgpath = Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString() +  "\\Image" + imagecount + ".bmp";

              // create a memory stream
              MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream(listener.Images[j]);
              // create a FIBITMAP from that stream
              FIBITMAP dib = FreeImage.LoadFromStream(imageStream);

              if (dib.IsNull) continue;
             //turn it into a normal Bitmap 
             Bitmap bitmap = FreeImage.GetBitmap(dib);
             bitmap.Save(imgpath);
             //unload the FIBITMAP 
             FreeImage.UnloadEx(ref dib);
             bitmap.Dispose();

             System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imgpath);



           }





  public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
 {
    PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.GetImage();    
    if (renderInfo.GetRef() != null && image != null)
    {

      byte[] tempImage = image.GetImageAsBytes();                                  
      ImageNames.Add(string.Format("0}.bmp",renderInfo.GetRef().Number));
      Images.Add(tempImage);

     }             


}
```

I followed the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247336/add-freeimage-net-to-solution) to add FreeImage .Net to solution