# How to save psd layers in png using PSD-plugin for Paint.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, photoshop, psd, paint.net

How to save PSD layers in png using PSD-plugin for Paint.NET?

Trying to do this way:

```
System.Drawing.Image img;
var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
var BRW = new PhotoshopFile.BinaryReverseWriter(stream);
var psd = new PhotoshopFile.PsdFile();
psd.Load("c:\\1.psd");
psd.Layers[0].Save(BRW);
stream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream, true, true);
img.Save("c:\\1.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

But the line
img = Image.FromStream(stream, true, true);
throws "Parameter is not valid" exception.

Any other solutions via C#/C++ are also acceptable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/629955/635634. The most relevant answer to that question basically says your stream is corrupt. I doubt `System.Drawing.Image` understands psd format.

Comment: Not a duplicate. I'm finding a solution for the problem, not the reason of error in wrong solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about asking the author of the PSD plugin? Paint.NET isn't licensed for use as an SDK, by the way, only as an application.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution does not work anymore with the latest version, use instead:

```
var psd = new PhotoshopFile.PsdFile("YourPhotoshop Path as string", Encoding.ASCII);

// or

var psd = new PhotoshopFile.PsdFile("Your Photoshop File Path as string", Encoding.Default);
```

Same with saving.