# System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Parameter not valid” exception loading System.Drawing.Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629955/parameter-not-valid-exception-loading-system-drawing-image)

I am inserting a image in the DB.

Here's my code

```
public class ImageUtils
{
    const int sizeThumb = 69;

    public static int uploadImage(int memberid, Image thumbimage)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        thumbimage.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        Byte[] thumbbytes = stream.ToArray();

        //int length = Convert.ToInt32(data.Length);
        //byte[] thumbimage = new byte[length];
        //data.Read(thumbimage, 0, length);
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FMMImages"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update Images_temp set thumbimage = @thumbimage where memberid=@memberid", connection);
        SqlParameter param0 = new SqlParameter("@thumbimage", SqlDbType.Image);
        param0.Value = thumbbytes;
        command.Parameters.Add(param0);

        connection.Open();

        object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();
        if (result != null)
        {
            return System.Convert.ToInt32(result);
        }
        else
        { 
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

aspx.cs where I'm calling the uploadimage
      image CroppedWaterMarkImage
        ......

```
    ImageUtils.uploadImage(memberid, CroppedWaterMarkImage);
```

Error in the uploadimage function:

```
     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
     thumbimage.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
     Byte[] thumbbytes = stream.ToArray();
```

> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.

Thanks
Sun

Comment: If you debug, which line does it stop on?

Comment: If the C# database libraries are anything like the Java ones, then wouldn't you pass "thumbimage" to the `SqlParameter` constructor instead of "@thumbimage"?  Also, you don't seem to be setting a value for the "@memberid" parameter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629955/parameter-not-valid-exception-loading-system-drawing-image

Answer (score 1):

These guys encountered a similar problem with Images and MemoryStream() because of a memory leak:

- http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2007/11/29/The-Mysterious-Parameter-Is-Not-Valid-Exception.aspx

This link was resolved by calling System.Drawing.Bitmap instead of System.Drawing.Image:

- http://forums.asp.net/t/1705636.aspx/1
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Either (memory leak/corruption and/or choice of API) could be applicable to your scenario.

Also make sure the image file is valid.