# Parameter not valid - Image.FromStream 32bit Image

Tags: c#, image, .net-core, memorystream

I'm trying to create an image from the memory stream in which the image is a `32bit` depth `JPG`.

```
byte[] imgData = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\ABC\32bit.jpg");
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imgData))
    {
        Image img = Image.FromStream(ms, false); // Exception line "Parameter is not valid"
    }
```

Actually it works for many images which is either `24bit` or even a `32bit` PNG. It just not works for `32bit` JPG image.

Have tried these below solutions,

1

```
 Image x = (Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(imgData));
```

2

```
 System.Drawing.ImageConverter converter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
 Image img = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(imgData);
```

3

```
 ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

4

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms , true, false)
```

Any help on the possible error?

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629955/parameter-not-valid-exception-loading-system-drawing-image

Comment: @BWA I think that's my 4th solution which i have tried. Didn't help

Comment: You'll have to go shopping for a codec to handle this format, you won't get it from System.Drawing.  WIC has better support, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284353/is-there-a-good-way-to-convert-between-bitmapsource-and-bitmap